# float:left и transform:rotate. Возможно ли нормально упаковать div?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, transform

Можно ли притянуть серый блок к развёрнутому тексту?
Можно притянуть через сдвиг по `relative`, но тогда сдвигаются за пределы окна перемещённые на новую строку.

```css
#specSZ {
  position:relative;
  top:75px;
  left:-70px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;
  width:190px;
}
.specBox {
  left:-100px;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:silver;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="specSZ">ТЕКСТ</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
```

Comment: В принципе решил обернув ещё в один div. Но... как-то это не очень правильно кажется.

Answer (score 1):

так?

```css
#specSZ {
  position:relative;
  top:75px;
 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;

}
.specBox {
  left:-100px;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:silver;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<div id="specSZ">ТЕКСТ</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: И да и нет. Тут текст теряет размер контейнера. Но это тоже вариант хороший. В принципе - отличное решение. Спасибо. Я же обернул 

<div id="overRotateDiv"><div id="specSZ">Текст</div></div> 

и в css добавил. 

#overRotateDiv {
  width:65px;
  height:190px;
  margin:0em;
  padding:0em;
  float:left;
}

Костыль как я понимаю, но... Тут смысл в том, что возможно придётся границы видимые задавать. Но, ещё раз, большое спасибо за изящное простое решение.

Comment: А ещё перенос по словам теряется как я понял. Ну да это всё мелочи уже.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#overRotateDiv {
  width:65px;
  height:190px;
  margin:0em;
  padding:0em;
  float:left;
}


#specSZ {
  position:relative;
  top:75px;
 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;

}
.specBox {
  left:-100px;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:silver;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
 <div id="overRotateDiv"> 
    <div id="specSZ">ТЕКСТ</div>
 </div> 

<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```